# How can i get element from <td> in html with jsoup Android

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup

How can I get bolded element "THIS" from HTML using jsoup. My problem is that I don't know how to get to this element, because I need to detect if its from `<tr>` "Ulica" first. what do I need to put in `document.select(...)`? Any ideas? Thanks.

```
<table class="InfoTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="Name">Ulica:</td>
        <td class="Value"><span id="ctl00_RightContentPlaceholder_lbAregStreet">**THIS**</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Name">Mesto:</td>
        <td class="Value"><span id="ctl00_RightContentPlaceholder_lbAregCity">XXXXX</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Name">PSČ:</td>
        <td class="Value"><span id="ctl00_RightContentPlaceholder_lbAregZip">XXXX</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Name">Štát:</td>
        <td class="Value"><span id="ctl00_RightContentPlaceholder_lbAregCountry">XXXXX</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Take a look at this. http://krishnasblog.com/2012/12/02/jsoup-nice-way-to-do-html-parsing-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all that into a single [selector](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

**Example:**

```
// html is your posted html code here, you can connect to a website too.
final String html = ...
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); // Parse into document

// Select the element and print it
for( Element element : doc.select("td:contains(Ulica:) ~ td") )
{
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

**Explanation:**

`td:contains(Ulica:) ~ td`: Selects `td` elements with text `Ulicia`, and takes the next *sibling* element that's a `td`.

**Output:**

```
<td class="Value"><span id="ctl00_RightContentPlaceholder_lbAregStreet">**THIS**</span></td>
```

Now you can get the values you need form that element.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://krishnasblog.com/2012/12/02/jsoup-nice-way-to-do-html-parsing-in-java/); it is a nice way to do HTML parsing in Java.

```
String html="<table class=\"InfoTable\"<tr><td class=\"Name\">Ulica:</td> <td class=\"Value\"><span id=\"ctl00_RightContentPlaceholder_lbAregStreet\">**THIS**</span></td></tr><tr><td class=\"Name\">Mesto:</td><td class=\"Value\"><span id=\"ctl00_RightContentPlaceholder_lbAregCity\">XXXXX</span></td></tr></table>";
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Iterator<Element> productList = doc.select("table[class=InfoTable]").iterator();

while (productList.hasNext()) {
    //Do some processing
    Element descLi = productList.next().select( "td:eq(1)").first();
    String rr = descLi.text();
    Log.d("TESTTT",rr );
}
```